# По какой то причине вылетает консольное приложение C#, когда я перехожу к следующему пункту помогите!, я набираю 2 затем 6 и оно прекращает работу!

Tags: c#

```
 static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        string choise1 = "Добаваить товар";
        string choise2 = "Изменить добавленный товар";
        string choise3 = "Удалить товар (на данный момет невозможно)";
        string choise4 = "Посмотреть товар";
        string choise5 = "Выйти";
        string choise6 = "изменение артикула";
        string choise7 = "изменение названия товара";
        string choise8 = "Изменение компании производителя";
        string choise9 = "изменение количества товара";
        string choise10 = "изменение цены";
        string choise11 = "Изменение категории";
        string id;
        string name;
        string companyName;
        string price;
        string category;
        int Nal;
        int userInput;

        Console.WriteLine("Добропожаловать в электронный справочник компании <Freestyle>. Что вы хотели бы сделать?");

        Console.WriteLine("1 - Добаваить товар");
        Console.WriteLine("2 - Изменить товар");
        Console.WriteLine("3 - Удалить товар (на данный момет невозможно)");
        Console.WriteLine("4 - Посмотреть какой товар есть");
        Console.WriteLine("5 - Выйти");

        userInput = Convert.ToInt32(Console.ReadLine());

        if (userInput == 1)
        {
            Console.WriteLine("Введите данные.");
            Console.Write("Ведите Артикул: ");
            id = Console.ReadLine();
            Console.Write("Ведите Название товара: ");
            name = Console.ReadLine();
            Console.Write("Ведите название компании производителя: ");
            companyName = Console.ReadLine();
            Console.Write("Ведите Количество товара: ");
            Nal = Convert.ToInt32(Console.ReadLine());
            if (Nal <= 0)
            {
                Console.Write("Ведите цену за единицу товара: ");
                price = Console.ReadLine();
                Console.Write("Ведите Категорию товара: ");

                category = Console.ReadLine();

                Console.WriteLine($"Артикул: {id}; Название товара: {name}; Компания: {companyName}; Наличае товара: Отсутствует; Цена: 0; Категория: {category}");
                Console.ReadKey();
            }
            else
            {
                Console.Write("Ведите цену за единицу товара: ");
                price = Console.ReadLine();
                Console.Write("Ведите Категорию товара: ");
                category = Console.ReadLine();

                Console.WriteLine($"Артикул: {id}; Название товара: {name}; Компания: {companyName}; Наличае товара: {Nal}; Цена: {price}; Категория: {category}");
                Console.ReadKey();
            }
        }
        if (userInput == 2)
        {

            Console.WriteLine("(пример изменения товара) Какой параметр вы хотите изменить?:");

            Console.WriteLine("6 - Артикул");
            Console.WriteLine("7 - Названи товара");
            Console.WriteLine("8 - Компания производителя");
            Console.WriteLine("9 - Наличае товара");
            Console.WriteLine("10 - цена");
            Console.WriteLine("11 - Категория");
            Console.ReadKey();


            if (userInput == 6)
            {
                Console.Write("Введите новый артикул:");
                id = Console.ReadLine();
                Console.WriteLine($"Артикул: {id}; Название товара: BMX tailwhip; Компания: BMX; Наличае товара: 14; Цена: 14999р; Категория: Велосипеды");
                Console.ReadKey();
            }
            else if (userInput == 7)
            {
                Console.Write("Введите новое название:");
                name = Console.ReadLine();
                Console.WriteLine($"Артикул: MP-12-BN-14; Название товара: {name}; Компания: BMX; Наличае товара: 14; Цена: 14999р; Категория: Велосипеды");
                Console.ReadKey();
            }
            else if (userInput == 8)
            {
                Console.Write("Введите новое название компании:");
                companyName = Console.ReadLine();
                Console.WriteLine($"Артикул: MP-12-BN-14; Название товара: BMX tailwhip; Компания: {companyName} ; Наличае товара: 14; Цена: 14999р; Категория: Велосипеды");
                Console.ReadKey();

            }
            else if (userInput == 9)
            {
                Console.Write("Ведите новое количество товара: ");
                Nal = Convert.ToInt32(Console.ReadLine());
                if (Nal <= 0)
                {
                    Console.WriteLine($"Артикул: MP-12-BN-14; Название товара: BMX tailwhip; Компания: BMX; Наличае товара: Отсутствует; Цена: 0; Категория: Велосипеды");
                    Console.ReadKey();
                }
                else
                {
                    Console.WriteLine($"Артикул: MP-12-BN-14; Название товара: BMX tailwhip; Компания: BMX; Наличае товара: {Nal}; Цена: 14999р; Категория: Велосипеды");
                    Console.ReadKey();

                }

            }
            else if (userInput == 10)
            {
                Console.Write("Введите новую цену:");
                price = Console.ReadLine();
                Console.WriteLine($"Артикул: MP-12-BN-14; Название товара: BMX tailwhip; Компания: BMX; Наличае товара: 14; Цена: {price}; Категория: Велосипеды");
                Console.ReadKey();
            }
            else if (userInput == 11)
            {
                Console.Write("Введите новую категорию:");
                category = Console.ReadLine();
                Console.WriteLine($"Артикул: MP-12-BN-14; Название товара: BMX tailwhip; Компания: BMX; Наличае товара: 14; Цена: 14999р; Категория: {category}");
                Console.ReadKey();
            }
        }
        if (userInput == 3)
        {
            Console.WriteLine("Простите но в данной версии программы эта функция не работает :)");
            Console.ReadKey();
        }
        if (userInput == 4)
        {
            Console.WriteLine("Выберите место нахождения товара:");

            Console.WriteLine("12 - склад магазина");
            Console.WriteLine("13 - Главное помещение");
            Console.ReadKey();
            if (userInput == 12)
            {
                Console.WriteLine("Выберите категорию товара:");
                Console.WriteLine("14. Велосипеды");
                Console.WriteLine("15. Самокаты");
                Console.ReadKey();
                if (userInput == 14)
                {
                    Console.WriteLine("На данный момент на складе содержатся:");
                    Console.WriteLine("1.Артикул: MP-12-BN-14; Название товара: BMX tailwhip; Компания: BMX; Наличае товара: 14; Цена: 14999р; Категория: Велосипеды");
                    Console.WriteLine("2.Артикул: MP-13-BN-15; Название товара: BMX StartForm; Компания: BMX; Наличае товара: 60; Цена: 16999р; Категория: Велосипеды");
                    Console.WriteLine("3.Артикул: MP-14-GN-16; Название товара: Cube Aim Race; Компания: Cube; Наличае товара: 10; Цена: 82950р; Категория: Велосипеды");
                    Console.WriteLine("3.Артикул: MP-15-GN-17; Название товара: Cube Access WS; Компания: Cube; Наличае товара: 5; Цена: 65600р; Категория: Велосипеды");
                }
                else if (userInput == 15)
                {
                    Console.WriteLine("На данный момент на складе содержатся:");
                    Console.WriteLine("1.Артикул: MP-16-CN-14; Название товара: Razor A5 Lux; Компания: Razor; Наличае товара: 17; Цена: 20859р; Категория: Самокаты");
                    Console.WriteLine("2.Артикул: MP-17-VN-16; Название товара: Weelz ROCK; Компания: ROCK; Наличае товара: 80; Цена: 24500р; Категория: Самокаты");
                    Console.WriteLine("3.Артикул: MP-18-ON-17; Название товара: Oxelo Town; Компания: Oxelo; Наличае товара: 14; Цена: 5950р; Категория: Самокаты");
                    Console.WriteLine("3.Артикул: MP-19-IN-20; Название товара: Indigo Vamos; Компания: Vamos; Наличае товара: 7; Цена: 7600р; Категория: Самокаты");
                };
            }
            else if (userInput == 13)
            {
                Console.WriteLine("Выберите категорию товара:");
                Console.WriteLine("14. Велосипеды");
                Console.WriteLine("15. Самокаты");
                Console.ReadKey();
                if (userInput == 14)
                {
                    Console.WriteLine("На данный момент на складе содержатся:");
                    Console.WriteLine("1.Артикул: MP-12-BN-14; Название товара: BMX tailwhip; Компания: BMX; Наличае товара: 6; Цена: 14999р; Категория: Велосипеды");
                    Console.WriteLine("2.Артикул: MP-13-BN-15; Название товара: BMX StartForm; Компания: BMX; Наличае товара: 8; Цена: 16999р; Категория: Велосипеды");
                    Console.WriteLine("3.Артикул: MP-14-GN-16; Название товара: Cube Aim Race; Компания: Cube; Наличае товара: 5; Цена: 82950р; Категория: Велосипеды");
                    Console.WriteLine("3.Артикул: MP-15-GN-17; Название товара: Cube Access WS; Компания: Cube; Наличае товара: 7; Цена: 65600р; Категория: Велосипеды");
                }
                else if (userInput == 15)
                {
                    Console.WriteLine("На данный момент на складе содержатся:");
                    Console.WriteLine("1.Артикул: MP-16-CN-14; Название товара: Razor A5 Lux; Компания: Razor; Наличае товара: 7; Цена: 20859р; Категория: Самокаты");
                    Console.WriteLine("2.Артикул: MP-17-VN-16; Название товара: Weelz ROCK; Компания: ROCK; Наличае товара: 8; Цена: 24500р; Категория: Самокаты");
                    Console.WriteLine("3.Артикул: MP-18-ON-17; Название товара: Oxelo Town; Компания: Oxelo; Наличае товара: 1; Цена: 5950р; Категория: Самокаты");
                    Console.WriteLine("3.Артикул: MP-19-IN-20; Название товара: Indigo Vamos; Компания: Vamos; Наличае товара: 9; Цена: 7600р; Категория: Самокаты");
                }
            }
        }
        if (userInput == 5)
        {
            Environment.Exit(0);
        }

    }
}
```

}

Comment: Если описать проблему, то я сделал выбор пользователям однако почему то пользователь может выбрать лишь первый пункт введя число от 1 до 5, если ввести число 2, то появляется новый столбец выбора, однако при вводе любого символа консольное приложение тут же выключается, помогите пж, парюсь уже 4 дня, кто не понимает о чем я вставьте этот код в visual studio в качестве консольного приложения и запустите

Comment: люди помогите пожалуйста, я щас заплачу

Comment: вы в userInput записываете число только один раз, а значит, переменная принимает то значение и больше не меняется.

Comment: таким образом, из всех ваших `if (userInput == ...)` срабатывает только какой то один, после этого ваша программа ничего не делает, просто заканчивается

Comment: подскажите пожалуйста как мне это исправить, может можно заменить чем то?

Comment: могу сказать, что здесь нужно разбить код на несколько блоков/функций типа добавление/редактирование/удаление товара, категории, локации и пр.  Или лучше классов, каждый со своими полями и методами. Затем использовать рекурсивный вызов на начальное меню или на верхний уровень (проще говоря "назад").